# Why can I have two mut reference if use From trait?

Tags: rust, reference

Code as follow, `RefInner` has two mut ref of `Inner` and `Inner.a`, use `From` trait the code has no err, but `cp()` will show `cannot borrow` inner `as mutable more than once at a time`. err detail is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `inner` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:40:12
   |
37 |       let b: RefInner = RefInner {
   |  _______________________-
38 | |         // b: a.geta().into(), //no error
39 | |         b: cp(inner.geta()),
   | |               ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
40 | |         a: &mut inner,
   | |            ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
41 | |     };
   | |_____- first borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
warning: `hello` (bin "hello") generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `hello` due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Inner {
    pub a: u64,
    pub b: u64,
}

pub struct RefInner<'a> {
    pub a: &'a mut Inner,
    pub b: &'a mut ResponseContext,
}

impl Inner {
    fn geta(&mut self) -> &mut u64 {
        &mut self.a
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ResponseContext {
    seq_id: u8,
    _ignore: [u8; 7],
}

impl From<&mut u64> for &mut ResponseContext {
    fn from(value: &mut u64) -> Self {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(value) }
    }
}

fn cp(n: &mut u64) -> &mut ResponseContext {
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(n) }
}

fn main() {
    let mut inner: Inner = Inner { a: 1, b: 2 };
    let b: RefInner = RefInner {
        // b: a.geta().into(), //no error
        b: cp(inner.geta()), //cannot borrow `inner` as mutable more than once at a time
        a: &mut inner,
    };
}
```

**Can anyone explain the difference？**

Comment: Note that this code has UB - it already triggers Miri as it is in the post, so the question is much less meaningful then it might appear to be.

Comment: yep，`_ignore: [u8; 9]` should be `_ignore: [u8; 7]`, but has no affect to the question

Comment: This is still UB with `[u8; 7]` - the problem is not only the size mismatch, the problem is aliasing mutable references.

Comment: Can you explain what the UB is? I can not see that.

Comment: Both references inside `RefInner` point to the same memory. Since they're mutable, according to Rust rules, this is UB.

Comment: Coder(me)  will be responsible for that since using unsafe block.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm pointing at - you're responsible for not putting this code in production, since you don't know what it will be compiled to.

Comment: I know there has two reference and rust do not allow that, so I question here. This code will be put in production and I think is ok even if I do not see the answer. Know there has two ref to the same memory is enough as writing C code.

Comment: I mean, aliasing mutable reference is UB in Rust _by definition_. C doesn't have it, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252067/discussion-between-vicios-and-cerberus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your trait implementation here with lifetimes ellision, the input and output lifetimes are [disjoint](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff140c7d0f768cd9ea7683610d130296).

i.e in your case it is `impl<'a, 'b> From<&'a mut u64> for &'b mut ResponseContext`.

With `transmute()`, you are telling the compiler to [ignore it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8b50bce0a69a1f40e3fdc0607a246bb).

As for the function with one input and one output, the compiler assigns same lifetime.

`fn cp(n: &mut u64) -> &mut ResponseContext`  is basically `fn cp<'a>(n: &'a mut64) -> &'a mut ResponseContext`

If you do `impl<'a> From<&'a mut u64> for &'a mut ResponseContext`, it will behave like your function `cp()`

Comment: Any doc about this? What `'b` lifetime is in trait implementation? `'static`?

Comment: It along with `'a` is 'some' lifetime that could also be `'static` but are not related

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer boils down to the elision rules.

When you have `impl From<&mut A> for &mut B`, this implementation header is desugared to `impl<'from, 'to> From<&'from mut A> for &'to mut B`, that is, it allows converting *any* reference (however short) to *any* reference (however long). In general, these two lifetimes have to be connected, since otherwise the method body would not compile, but here you've forced the borrow checker to accept this general implementation with `transmute`.

When you have `fn(&mut A) -> &mut B`, however, this is desugared in more specific way - namely, to `fn<'lt>(&'lt mut A) -> &'lt mut B`, i.e. input and output lifetimes are equivalent - therefore, the original mutable reference is "locked" as long as the output reference exists, preventing any other usage.